# Верный ли синтаксис запроса?

Tags: pdo, запрос, mysql

Есть запрос

```
UPDATE files SET load = :load, count = :count WHERE id = :id
```

При выполнении которого, всплывают ошибки

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load = '1404402799', count = '1' where id = '13'' at line 1' in C:\OpenServer\domains\img.com\engine\db.php on line 37

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load = '1404402799', count = '1' where id = '13'' at line 1 in C:\OpenServer\domains\img.com\engine\db.php on line 37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверный (вообще-то об этом говорится английским по-белому). Или не используйте для своих целей зарезервированные слова, или заворачивайте их в обратные кавычки:

- [LOAD](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/load-data.html)
- [COUNT](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/group-by-functions.html)

Первый вариант (не использовать) правильней.